# How to navigate a library in Native Code in intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, z3

I am basically running a java library 'Z3' that invokes some native functions, I believe they are written in c++. 
I can use the library and subsequently the native function just fine, but I just want to sometimes navigate into the source of the native code. That is during debugging, I want to trace execution happening inside the Jar files but I cannot navigate to the disassembly of the native code. 
In summary, it looks like the native library is there, otherwise the execution won't be happening but I am unable to navigate to its code. I am using intellij ULTIMATE 2017.2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functionality you're looking for does not exist. As of version 2018.3, IntelliJ IDEA has no support for working with native code in any way.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and for saving me more hours of trying to make it happen.